# Where can I get Debian initial version ISOs?

Tags: debian, system-installation, distribution-media

I am interested in installing initial versions of Debian on VirtualBox. Can anybody tell me where I can find these ISOs?

Comment: do you mean very old versions if Debian? If that's the case, they won't contain .isos ([buzz](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/buzz/main/) has floppy disk images of v1.1)

Comment: The question is unclear. Define "initial versions", please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all of the old debian versions at the [Offical Debian Archives](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/). When you've got the floppy image, you can use [this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/floppy_image_on_cd.htm) tutorial to convert the .img to a .iso

Comment: There are binaries on `archive.debian.org`, including boot floppies, but last time I looked I couldn't find the ISOs of old versions there or anywhere. P.S. [please don't use a signature in your posts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, I did not know about the rule about signatures.